# Include glfw3 headers fails with CLion / WSL / Conan toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, conan

I am setting up a C++ CLion project to learn OpenGL, I started by adding the GLFW dependency with Conan on a WSL system on Windows, and I can't manage to include the GLFW headers after successfully configuring my CMake project.

I am using :

- CLion 2020.3 with a configured WSL toolchain
- CMake 3.10.2
- Conan 1.32.1
- GLFW 3.3.2, from the conan-center remote

I can manage to run the [Getting started](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) example of conan without any issues, but installing GLFW seems to be a bit more involved than poco.
I can locate the desired header in the .conan directory, but for some reason it is not visible at link time, a piece is missing here.

### Code

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(learn_opengl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

add_executable(learn_opengl main.cpp)
message("CONAN LIBS: ${CONAN_LIBS}")
conan_target_link_libraries(learn_opengl ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
glfw/3.3.2

[generators]
cmake
```

The error at compile-time :

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
```

I have to dive deeper to understand the compilation process here and the way Conan and CMake interact, any help or shortcut would be great as I find myself a bit clueless here, many thanks.

Comment: If you're using wsl/Linux you need to use forward slashes not back slashes

Comment: ... and that was it, my eyes did not catch it. Thank you very much.